# "mobile"-blogging - any ideas/existing solutions?

Tags: php, html, css, scripting, blogs

does anyone know any sort of app that lets users visit a page on their mobile phone, enter information and have it update the website

i believe the term is "mobile-blogging" but there isn't all that much on google

or, is there any good resources for coding pages specifically for a mobile phone? I could probably design a script to insert blog posts on a site but not sure how it would work with a mobile.

thanks for any pointers

Comment: in what sense? like twitter? could you provide more examples?

Comment: well atm we intend to use a CMS like ModX to maintain the site, but would like to perhaps update parts of it from say a mobile phone.

might be a question best left to the community forums. 

im more interested in any special requirements to coding my own app for instance if that makes a little more sense and integrating it with other systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably isn't an app because there isn't a need for an app. Most blogging software has a number of options/plugins for enabling "remote" blogging. Either by sending an email to a special address, or having a "theme" designed for a mobile phone. Both MoveableType/Typepad and WordPress have plugins to "blog/admin" from a mobile platform.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use web browsing apps like [Opera Mini](http://www.operamini.com), and it will work with many of the existing blog services out there. ([My Opera](http://my.opera.com) blogs are naturally well adapted for Opera Mini usage as far as I know.)